# Simple slider for products items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

I want to make a slider for pictures in the goods but it does not work. how can i fix it?
i have that error 
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

```
    in div (at src/index.js:63)
    in div (at src/index.js:62)
    in div (at src/index.js:61)
    in App (at src/index.js:82)
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Product 1",
          price: 50,
          q: 0,
          category: "Sporting Goods",
          imgs: [
            "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property04.jpg",
            "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property02.jpg",
            "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property01.jpg",
            "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property03.jpg"
          ],
          currSlide: 0
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Product 2",
          price: 70,
          q: 0,
          category: "Sporting Goods",
          imgs: [
            "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property04.jpg",
            "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property02.jpg",
            "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property01.jpg",
            "https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/_rw/01-real-estate/tn_property03.jpg"
          ],
          currSlide: 0
        }
      ],
      products: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      products: [...this.state.data]
    });
  }
  nextProperty = item => {
    const { id, name, price, q, category, imgs, currSlide } = item;

    this.setState({
      products: [
        ...this.state.products,
        { id, name, price, q, category, imgs, currSlide: currSlide + 1 }
      ]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="page">
          <div className="collection">
            {this.state.products.map(item => (
              <div key={item.id} className="product">
                <div className="product__image">
                  <img src={item.imgs[item.currSlide]} alt="#" />
                  <button onClick={() => this.nextProperty(item)}>Next</button>
                </div>
                <div className="product__name">{item.name}</div>
                <div className="product__price">{item.price}$</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: What is the unexpected behaviour? Can you give details about the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your key problem happens because in your array you may have 2 objects with the same id, your id should be unique or you should use this :

```
{this.state.products.map((item,i) => {
   <div key={i} className="product">
})
```

Comment: Now there is no error. But it adds an new element to the end of the array

Comment: stackoverflow is question and you  may get the answer :v you asked for keys you got keys fixed

Comment: for the other question,  edit the question with as many details as possible or you can post another question in here :) feel free to upvote

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lays here

```
this.setState({
      products: [
        ...this.state.products,
        { id, name, price, q, category, imgs, currSlide: currSlide + 1 }
      ]
    });
```

The **`id`** should be **`id+1`** isn't it?

You are adding new **`item`** but **`id`** remain same, which create duplicate id in your array and hence **`key={item.id}`** loses its uniqueness